# Ionic 2: Can we perform cookie based authentication in ionic2

Tags: ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app, ngcordova

My ionic version is 2.1.17 and cordova version is 6.4.0. In my application I need perform cookie based user authentication. I read in many places which says you cannot perform cookie based authentication in ionic. So is there way with I can create cookie based authentication in ionic 2?